# How to create a grid in Qt with colors?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to do something very similar to this image in Qt where I can click in any square and change the color of it.

[image]

Comment: You should look to the QTableView class. Using this, you can represent the image provided. Then, each time the click signal is emited in a cell it open the QColorDialog class so you can pick the color to update.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, depending on your use case. How large will this scale? If it's always the size of the provided image, `QTableView`, as mentioned above, is a good bet. If you're dealing with lots and lots of squares or want to do more interaction than just changing colors, `QGraphicsScene`/`QGraphicsView` or QML may be called for.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to do this with QML. Look at the code below:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 500
    Column{
        Repeater{
            model: getRowsNumber(root.height)
            delegate: Row{
                property int externalIdx: index
                Repeater{
                    model: getColumnsNumber(root.width)
                    delegate: Rectangle{
                        property bool selected: false
                        property color originalColor: (index + externalIdx) % 2 == 0 ? "black" : "white"

                        width:20
                        height: 20
                        color: selected ? "red" : originalColor
                        border.width: 1
                        border.color: "black"
                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: parent.selected = !parent.selected
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getColumnsNumber(width){
        return width/20;
    }
    function getRowsNumber(height){
        return height/20;
    }
}
```

That's all you need to have a rectangular chess-like grid where each cell changes its color when it is clicked on. Of course, you will need to adapt it to your needs but that should be enough for you to start.